# Bash ping output in csv format

Tags: bash, csv, ping

My aim is to transform the output (the last 2 lines) of the ping command in a CSV style.

Here are some examples:

In case there is a packet loss lower than 100% <

```
 URL, PacketLoss, Min, Average, Max, Deviation
```

In case there is packet loss equal to 100%

```
 URL, 100, -1, -1, -1, -1
```

My script is below, but when the packet loss is 100% the output is:

```
URL, 100,
```

So the problem is at the if statement, as it does not enter in elif, I use the same syntax as checking if the address is full or not (with "www." or not).

Can you please have a look because I tried multiple things and it did not work.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare site=''
declare result='';

if [[ "$1" == "www."* ]]; then
        site="$1";
else
        site="www.$1";
fi

result="$site";

pingOutput=$(ping $site -c10 -i0.2 -q| tail -n2);

fl=true;

while IFS= read -r line
do

# !!! The problem is here, the if statement is not working properly and I do not know why !!!

        if [ "$fl" == "true" ]; then
                result="$result $(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f3 | cut -d" " -f2 | sed -r 's/%//g')";
                fl=false;
        elif [[ "$line" == "ms"* ]]; then
                result="$result $(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f4 | sed -r 's/\// /g')";
        else
                result="$result -1 -1 -1 -1";
        fi
done <<< "$pingOutput"

echo "$result";
```

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr for editing the post, I am quite new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: would be good if you add examples of pingOutput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second line of the pingOutput was never processed (the loop ended before) the action of adding the -1 to the output was never performed.

Due to this problem I decided to capture the percentage of failure and act when no packets were returned (100%), I also simplified some expressions you used initially.

I investigated the script and came up with the following solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare site=''
declare result=''
declare prctg=''

[[ "$1" == "www."* ]] && site="$1" || site="www.$1"

result="$site"

pingOutput=$(ping $site -c10 -i0.2 -q| tail -n2)

fl=true

while IFS= read -r line
do
# !!! The problem is here, the if statement is not working properly and I do not know why !!!
echo $line
if [ "$fl" == "true" ]
    then
        prctg=$(echo "$line" | grep -Po "[0-9]{0,3}(?=%)")
        result="$result $prctg"
        fl=false
    fi
if [ "$prctg" == "100" ]
    then
        result="$result -1 -1 -1 -1"
    else
        result="$result $(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f4 | sed -r 's/\// /g')"
    fi
done <<< "$pingOutput"

echo "$result"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old question but I've just stumbled upon it today. Below I paste a slight modified version of the above script that fixes the `if` issue and works on Mac OS.

P.S. You can uncomment the `# prctg=100.0%` line to see the `if` working.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare site=''
declare result=''
declare prctg=''

[[ "$1" == "www."* ]] && site="$1" || site="www.$1"

result="$site"

pingOutput=$(ping $site -c10 -i0.2 -q | tail -n2)

fl=true

while IFS= read -r line
do
  #echo $line
  if [ "$fl" == "true" ]
  then
    prctg=$(echo "$line" | grep -Eo "[.[:digit:]]{1,10}%")
    result="$result,$prctg"
    fl=false
   # prctg=100.0%
  else
    if [ "$prctg" == "100.0%" ]
    then
      result="$result,-1,-1,-1,-1"
    else
      result="$result,$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f4 | sed -E 's/\//,/g')"
    fi
  fi
done <<< "$pingOutput"

echo "$result"
```

I hope it helps someone from the future! :)